# Creating an adjacency List for DFS

Tags: c++, algorithm, depth-first-search

I'm having trouble creating a Depth First Search for my program. So far I have a class of edges and a class of regions. I want to store all the connected edges inside one node of my region. I can tell if something is connected by the getKey() function I have already implemented. If two edges have the same key, then they are connected. For the next region, I want to store another set of connected edges inside that region, etc etc. However, I am not fully understanding DFS and I'm having some trouble implementing it. I'm not sure when/where to call DFS again. Any help would be appreciated!

```
class edge
{ 
  private:
  int source, destination, length;
  int key;
  edge *next;
  public:
  getKey(){ return key; } 
}

class region
{
   edge *data;
   edge *next;
   region() { data = new edge(); next = NULL; }

};

void runDFS(int i, edge **edge, int a)
{
  region *head = new region();
  aa[i]->visited == true;//mark the first vertex as true
  for(int v = 0; v < a; v++)
  {
    if(tem->edge[i].getKey() == tem->edge[v].getKey()) //if the edges of the vertex have the same root
    {
        if(head->data == NULL)
        {
          head->data = aa[i];
          head->data->next == NULL;
        } //create an edge
        if(head->data)
        {
          head->data->next = aa[i];
          head->data->next->next == NULL;
        }//if there is already a node connected to ti
    }
    if(aa[v]->visited == false)
      runDFS(v, edge, a); //call the DFS again
  } //for loop
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming n is total number of edges, k is final number of regions.
Creating adjacency list for the requisite DFS might be too costly O(n^2) (if k=1 i.e. all edges belong to same region) and hence dfs will cost you O(V+E) i.e. O(n^2) in the worst case.

Otherwise problem is easily solvable in O(n * log(k)) as follows:

1. Traverse through all edges adding them to the head of corresponding regions (using balanced bst eg. stl-map) [you may use hashing for this too]
2. traverse through all the regions and connect them in requisite linear fashion

No guaranteed O(n) solution exists for the problem I guess..

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement a adjacency list creating function.The next pointer of adj_list struct takes you down the adjacency list(there is no relationship between 2 nodes connected by next) and the list pointer is the adjacency list. The node has the address of the adj_list which has its adjacency list.

```
struct node{
    int id;
    adj_list* adj;

};


struct adj_list{
    adj_list* next;
    adj_list* list;
    node* n;
    adj_list(node& _n){
        n = &(_n);
        next = NULL;
        list = NULL;
    }
};

node* add_node(int id,std::queue<int> q , node* root)
{
    node* n = new node(id);
    adj_list* adj = new adj_list(*n);
    n->adj = adj;

    if(root == NULL){
      return n;
    }
    std::queue<adj_list*> q1;

    while(1){
        adj_list* iter = root->adj;
        if(q.empty())break;
        int k = q.front();
        q.pop();
        while(iter){    
            if(iter->n->id == k){
                q1.push(iter);
                adj_list*  temp = iter->list;
                iter->list = new adj_list(*n);
                break;
            }
            iter = iter->next;
        }
    }

    adj_list* iter = root->adj;
    while(iter->next){
        iter = iter->next;
    }

    iter->next = adj;

    while(!q1.empty()){
        adj_list* temp = q1.front();
        q1.pop();
        adj->list = temp;
        adj = temp;
    }
    return root;
}
```